# Generating dynamic data for html table with both vertical and horizontal header

Tags: php, html, html-table

It's pretty simple to create a dynamic table with horizontal headers OR vertical headers alone. But how can I generate dynamic data for a table with BOTH vertical AND horizontal headers? Is this even possible?

**Table:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th scope="col">Monday</th>
        <th scope="col">Tuesday</th>
        <th scope="col">Wednesday</th>
        <th scope="col">Thursday</th>
        <th scope="col">Friday</th>
        <th scope="col">Saturday</th>
        <th scope="col">Sunday</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Week 1</th>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Week 2</th>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Week 3</th>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Week 4</th>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes it is. It can be done by dynamically generating the table. That is done with actual code, not with a [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model).

Comment: @Xorifelse: Okay I haven't thought of that. How would you go about this? I have no  clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be easily done in PHP. I've done a small example using a for-loop to give you an easier idea of how this might be accomplished

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th scope="col">Monday</th>
        <th scope="col">Tuesday</th>
        <th scope="col">Wednesday</th>
        <th scope="col">Thursday</th>
        <th scope="col">Friday</th>
        <th scope="col">Saturday</th>
        <th scope="col">Sunday</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        // Create week row
        for ($week = 0; $week < 10; $week++) {
            echo "            <tr>";
            echo "                <th scope='row'>Week " . $week . "</th>";

            // Create day cells
            for ($day = 0; $day <= 7; $day++) {
                echo "                <td>" . $day . "</td>";
            }

            echo "            </tr>";
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: This explains vertical (rows), not dynamic horizontal (cols).

Comment: Ah sorry, give me a second. EDIT: @Xor

Comment: @LFlare: so $x represents the variable that would be collected from the while statement or am I being mistaken?

Comment: @SebastianFarham Sorry, I made the variable names clearer and answered your question more specifically.

Comment: @LFlare: Your answer before that was already pretty legit. Good stuff. I think I'm just not being clear. I'm a total n00b in Php. With the for loop how      do I use a statement like this `<?php while($timemonday=mysqli_fetch_array($resultsheets)){ ?>` ? That's where my confusion is.

Comment: @SebastianFarham I'm not so sure what `$timemonday` is supposed to represent?

Comment: @LFlare: I want to retrieve users data from the table `activities` which holds users activity during a month. Logically there are only 4 Mondays, 4 Tuesdays etc., during a month. I want to display the data like a calendar showing what has been done during the whole month. To do so I thought about creating a query for each day of the week as follow : `$sqlMondayactivities="SELECT * FROM activities WHERE employee_id='$session_myemployeeid' AND timeinyear='$currentyear' AND timeinmonth='$currentmonth' AND timeinday='Monday'`

Comment: @LFlare: Okay I got it. It's just a matter of placing the weekdays vertically and the weeks horizontally so that the data will dynamically fit the specific weekday. I give you credits anyway.

Comment: `<th>` should only appear in the table as a head, this is *usually* **only** the first row instead of `<tr>`. Doing it this way produces an invalid DOM as `<th>` should never appear inside a `<tr>`.

Answer (score 1):

To dynamically generate a table horizontally and vertically, you will need 2 loops, the first one being for the amount of rows and the one inside of it for the cols.

```
<?php

  $rows = 10;
  $cols = 20;

  echo '<table>';
  for($r=0; $r <= $rows; $c++){
    echo "<tr>";
    for($c=0; $c <= $cols; $r++){
      echo "<td>$r</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo '</table>';

?>
```